# Flutter websocket

Tags: flutter, websocket

I'm building a real time flutter chat application using websocket.
i'm having issues on where and how to implement websocket so as to make sure that the user is always connected throughout the app. and whenever the user disconnect(due to poor internet connection or such), he will be reconnected automatically to websocket when he comes back online.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a websocket server firstly, and will also need to think about which protocol you wish to use for communication with those servers so that you can provide peer to peer communication across all clients. This topic is covered in depth in the post [building realtime apps with Flutter and WebSockets](https://www.ably.io/topic/websockets-flutter).  That's probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this multiplatform websocket package (reconnection feature included, just read the examples) https://pub.dev/packages/websocket_universal . There you can configure SocketConnectionOptions with `[timeoutConnectionMs]` , `[failedReconnectionAttemptsLimit]` and even `[maxReconnectionAttemptsPerMinute]`. And that package allows you to listen to webSocket events.
Small example:

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print
import 'package:websocket_universal/websocket_universal.dart';

/// Example works with Postman Echo server
void main() async {
  /// 1. Create webSocket handler:
  final textSocketHandler = IWebSocketHandler<String, String>.createClient(
    'wss://ws.postman-echo.com/raw', // Postman echo ws server
    SocketSimpleTextProcessor(),
  );

  /// 2. Listen to webSocket messages:
  textSocketHandler.incomingMessagesStream.listen((inMsg) {
    print('> webSocket  got text message from server: "$inMsg" '
        '[ping: ${textSocketHandler.pingDelayMs}]');
  });
  textSocketHandler.outgoingMessagesStream.listen((inMsg) {
    print('> webSocket sent text message to   server: "$inMsg" '
        '[ping: ${textSocketHandler.pingDelayMs}]');
  });

  /// 3. Connect & send message:
  await textSocketHandler.connect();
  textSocketHandler.sendMessage('Hello server!');
  await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));

  // 4. Disconnect & close connection:
  await textSocketHandler.disconnect('manual disconnect');
  textSocketHandler.close();
}
```